# restrict useEffect execution to only one dependency

Tags: reactjs

I´m playing with useEffect and i only need to "listen" to changes in one state but use another one without including it.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState(["Mike"]);
const [message, setMessage] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    users.length > 0 && setMessage("we have users"!)
}, [users])

setMessage("hello!") // If I add this dependency to the previous useEffect it will trigger. but I will only need it to trigger on users change
setUsers(["john", "mary"])
```

doing this React will complain about the setMessage dependency
what´s the correct use of useState if I only one to listen to one state?

I ended up using. not sure if is the best approach. I´m just sharing what I tried :)

```
useEffect(() => {
    users.length > 0 && functionIWantToExecuteOnceWithoutDependencies()
}, [users])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `eslint` is giving warning specifying that you have missed adding `setMessage` as a dependency. But in your case, it seems the `setMessage` is a state setter and won't be changed thought your render cycle. Hence you can either ignore the eslint warning or disable the warning.

You can [disable the warning](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880#issuecomment-493998947) like this:

```js
useEffect(
    () => {
      users.length > 0 && setMessage("we have users"!)
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [users],
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `setMessage` as a dependency. The react hook linter sees it as a called function, but since `setMessage` is a function created from the `useState` hook it is a stable reference so I won't cause any effect triggering.

You can disable lint rules per line if you want to, but that is generally not recommended. A scenario can arise where you update the effect, but because the dependency array linting is disabled you may introduce logical bugs.